# How to unit test a component that depends on React Router?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I'm pretty new with unit testing React, not unit testing in general and I have a couple of questions.

I do have a component which represents a page on which a user can authenticate.
Now, I do want to test this component, but I'm unsure which functionalities I should test and which functionalities I don't test.

For example, my component has some internal state which holds the currently entered username, password, an error for the username field, a password for the username field, ...

Should the state be tested in general or should I test the UI using `find` in enzyme.
For example, when I update the field containing the username, the updated username is stored in the state, and the button to authenticate becomes activated.

So, should I test that when I enter a value in the input field, that the state is updated, or should I test that the DOM is updated by chechking for a class on the submit button?

Also, this component has `Link` components in it using react router which makes it difficult to test.

Therefore, I'm using the following HOC to render a component and pass in a router stub.

```
export const stubRouterContext = (Component, props) => {
    function RouterStub() { }

    Object.assign(RouterStub, {
        makePath() {},
        makeHref() {},
        transitionTo() {},
        replaceWith() {},
        goBack() {},
        getCurrentPath() {},
        getCurrentRoutes() {},
        getCurrentPathname() {},
        getCurrentParams() {},
        getCurrentQuery() {},
        isActive() {},
        getRouteAtDepth() {},
        setRouteComponentAtDepth() {}
    });

    /**
     * Defines the component which contains stubbed router.
     *
     * @class RouterContextComponent
     * @extends {React.Component}
     */
    class RouterContextComponent extends React.Component {

        /**
         * Gets the child context of the component.
         *
         * @returns
         *
         * @memberof RouterContextComponent
         */
        getChildContext() {
            return {
                router: RouterStub,
                routeDepth: 0
            };
        }

        /**
        * Returns the HTML that represent the component.
        *
        * @memberof RouterContextComponent
        */
        render() {
            return <Component {...props} />
        }
    }

    /**
     * Defines the child context types of the component.
     */
    RouterContextComponent.childContextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.func,
        routeDepth: React.PropTypes.number
    };

    // Return the component that contains a stubbed router.
    return RouterContextComponent;
};
```

Now, I do have a unit test, but I'm unsure what to test.

```
let wrappedComponent = stubRouterContext(LoginPageComponent, {
    startBackgroundOperation: () => {},
    stopBackgroundOperation: () => {}
});

// Act.
const wrapper = mount(
    <wrappedComponent />
);
```

Any guidance is highly appreciated.